# Table prefixes in informatica SQL override

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I need help on automatic changes in table name prefix in SQL override.
My requirement is presently all my table are in 'abc' schema now the requirement is to moove all table in abc needs to move to xyz schema.

For this we need to give like xyz.emp in all SQL overrides. Is the any way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using SQL Overrides whenever possible. Now you know why...
2. Export - find 'n' replace - import should help you.